# Can't find Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library or FM20.DLL

Tags: excel, vba, windows-7, excel-2016

In my Excel 2016 project (Windows 7), I'd like to work with the clipboard:

```
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
```

But I've got this compiler Error at the first line of code:

> User-defined type not defined

So I would like to add the reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library but I have no `FM20.DLL` file on my entire computer (I have searched through explore and `find` with cygwin).

I expect to see it as in the screenshot below, but I can't find it.

[image: VBA list of available references]

How can I make it appear?

Comment: You don't need Forms 2.0 to work with the Windows clipboard - use the Win32 API instead, see [this thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev)

Comment: @Mat'sMug So legacy code can no longer work is that correct?  Here is one such code that I'm trying to get working. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14658/exporting-data-from-excel-into-mathematica-using-clipboard/14659#comment293526_14659

Comment: Are there any forms in your VBA project? If not, try adding one.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes already tried that.

Comment: You should mention it in your post then, because as it stands your question looks pretty much like an exact duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35610429/1188513).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes almost added a bounty on that but had no ability to accept the right answer.

Comment: The path to the FM20.DLL shown in the screenshot is totally different to the path I have on my system (Win7/Excel 2016). On my system it's at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FM20.DLL`

Comment: @barrowc Not there either.  I no longer have it open but I did a global search on my entire OS(I'm 99% sure it was done).

Comment: And have you tried to re-install Excel? When re-installing take care about the tools for Office and VBA.

Comment: Do you see it if you click on References browser?

Comment: @Om3r I did a search of my entire computer for such a file.  I will post if I determine if that works but it is most unlikely.

Comment: you may want to edit your tags with office and window version you are using

Comment: I'm positive the file was on there, the OP was just having trouble locating it.  It's a little late now but I would've asked *how* did you do this full search, and also explain that "99% sure" is not "sure"

Comment: @ashleedawg find command in cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this old knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224305) my guess would be this DLL is perhaps only included in older versions of Office? This part seemed promising:

> As an alternative to having your end users install Microsoft Office,
>   you can have them freely download and install the Microsoft ActiveX
>   Control Pad, which also installs the Fm20.dll. For more information,
>   see the following Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) Web site:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms968493.aspx

However, as the linked tool is from 1997, you'll need to run its setup in "compatibility mode" by right-clicking on the executable and selecting "Properties" then clicking on the "Compatibility" tab and selecting "Windows 95" in the "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" dropdown. Then run it as administrator (this worked for me using Windows 8.1).

Comment: Nope, FM20 should be in all Office installations which include VBA.

Comment: @jkpieterse It should but isn't always by evidence of the computers I have used. Also the link is 32bit only.  Funny thing I actually tried it before posting the question.  I didn't give the downvote by I will try the compatibility mode at some point although Im quite certain it won't work.

Comment: I've never had one without fm20.dll, so these must be incomplete Office installations. Try a full install. Note that if you have a click to run Office 2016 installation is streamed "as you go" so it might take some time before you have everything.

Answer (score 10):

On 64-bit machines, FM20.dll is in the `C:\Windows\sysWOW64` directory.  It's 32 bit.

Comment: This is the correct answer, don't be confused by the accepted answer...

Comment: Not only it is the correct answer, but does help explain this [strange behaviour that I noticed and asked why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57260380/2752308).

Comment: I have Office 64-bit and FM20.dll is not in the sysWOW64 folder, but is in the C:\Windows\System32 folder (strangely, only when browsing from the "References - VBAProject box, but is not visible in Windows Explorer even with all files showing including hidden/protected system files). I'm not sure if it will work correctly with Excel 64-bit, but so far so good.

Answer (score 2):

I found FM20.DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86; that's with MS Office 2016 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a late binding using the CLSID

Dim MyDataObj As Object
Set MyDataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to sort of summarize my experience and what I've seen listed here - `FM20.dll` can be found in any of these places:

```
C:\Windows\System32\
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\System\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\SystemX86\
```

Note that alternatively the GUID is:

```
{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also like to add that I have found that when a MS .accdb file is copied/pasted for back up, the VBA reference to the FM20.dll can be lost so needs to be reestablished.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the browse button seek C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe that's work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

That library should really be there. I just checked on my Excel 2016 installation (32 bit) and it is there by default (just not checked). I recommend to repair your Office if it isn't there.

Comment: What is the path to your file?