# VBA Copy/Paste Issues - PPTX Creation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Im using the below code to iterate over a table in excel that contains named ranges and position details for cells id like to copy over to a powerpoint presentation.

The code works perfectly. Except that, and for some reason its always random, the code throws a "Shapes.paste invalid request clipboard is empty" error. Debugging didnt help since it always stops at a different object or named range. I know VBA is a little finicky with its operations in that it starts the paste before actually completing the copy operation.

I tried the Application.Wait function which isnt the best solution, it slowed the code by 3 fold. As well do/doevents calls didnt help.

Any ideas on how to curb this VBA issue ??

Thanks!

```
 Sub MyProcedure(PPT As Object, WKSHEET As String, RangeTitle As Range, SlideNumber As Long, FTsize As Variant, FT As Variant, SetLeft As Variant, SetTop As Variant, SetHeight As Variant, SetWidth As Variant, Bool As Boolean)
    Dim shP As Object
    Dim myShape As Object
    Dim mySlide As Object
    Dim tempSize As Integer, tempFont As String
    Dim Mypath As String
    Dim Myname As String
    Dim myTitle As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Application.Calculation = xlManual
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Worksheets(WKSHEET)

    'select the name of report
    Set shP = ws.Range(RangeTitle)

    'select the ppt sheet you wish to copy the object to
    Set mySlide = PPT.ActivePresentation.slides(SlideNumber)

    'count the number of shapes currently on the PPT
    shapeCount = mySlide.Shapes.Count
    'copy the previously selected shape
    Do
    shP.Copy
    'paste it on the PPT
     DoEvents
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste 'Special DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse

    'wait until the count of shapes on the PPT increases, which signals that the past operation is finished.
     '<~~ wait completion of paste operation
    Loop Until mySlide.Shapes.Count > shapeCount

    'adjust formatting of the newly copied shape: position on the sheet, font & size
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = SetLeft
        .Top = SetTop
        .Width = SetWidth
        .Height = SetHeight
        .TextEffect.FontSize = FTsize
        .TextEffect.FontName = FT
        .TextEffect.FontBold = Bool

    End With
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub LoopThrougMyData()

    Dim FirstRow As Integer: FirstRow = 1
    Dim LastRow As Integer: LastRow = Worksheets("Table").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim PPT As Object

    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Myname = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=Mypath & "\Actuals Review Temp.pptx"

    For iRow = FirstRow To LastRow 'loop through your table here

        With Worksheets("Table").Range("test")
            MyProcedure PPT, WKSHEET:=.Cells(iRow, "A"), RangeTitle:=.Cells(iRow, "B"), SlideNumber:=.Cells(iRow, "C"), FTsize:=.Cells(iRow, "D"), FT:=.Cells(iRow, "E"), SetLeft:=.Cells(iRow, "F"), SetTop:=.Cells(iRow, "G"), SetHeight:=.Cells(iRow, "H"), SetWidth:=.Cells(iRow, "I"), Bool:=.Cells(iRow, "J")
            'call the procedure with the data from your table
        End With

    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to check the clipboard to see if it has an object available for pasting first. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384463/4717755) for details. The answer that follows that one has an important consideration.

Comment: Yes i've tried that method. At times VBA runs the Paste call before completing the Copy procedure, resulting in an temporarily empty clipboard that then throws the error. VBA seems to be jumping commands before the previous one finishes

Comment: Then loop with `DoEvents` for a limited time while checking the clipboard until the clipboard is non-empty? So your code can either exit (safely) with a timeout (that you control) or continue with the paste.

Answer (score 1):

**It's more than likely a clipboard issue.** This is a common bug in VBA when copying information from one application to the other application. T**he best solution I've found so far is simply pausing the Excel application for a few seconds in between the copy and paste.** Now this won't fix the issue in every single instance but I would say 95% of the time it fixes the error. The other 5% of the time is simply the information being removed from the clipboard randomly.

Change this section:

```
shP.Copy

'paste it on the PPT
DoEvents
mySlide.Shapes.Paste 'Special DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
```

With this:

```
'Copy the shape
 shP.Copy

'Pause the Excel Application For Two Seconds
Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#

'Paste the object on the slide as an OLEObject
mySlide.Shapes.Paste 'Special DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
```